How to embed Youtube live chat with dynamically updated url to the livestream?
Hey guys thanks for help!
I would like to permanently embed a YouTube live stream with chat to my website.
The problem is, that YouTube doesn't give permanent urls. Every live stream has unique stream ID.
However you can embed a YouTube livestream via link that always connects to the currently scheduled upcoming live stream VIDEOID:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID
This solves first half of the problem. The second half is the Live Chat which you can only embed if you know the live stream VIDEOID.
https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=VIDEOID&embed_domain=DOMAINURL
So what I would like to achieve:

Find the VIDEOID of the current upcoming Live Stream from this URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID

Get a Live Chat url containing that VIDEOID so I can embed it on my website and which will update every time the new live stream with new VIDEOID will be published.


I found the PHP code here that is supposed to achieve it but it returns an error "Couldn't find video ID". Probably because this code is from 2017 and the regex can't properly locate the VIDEOID in YouTube's updated code but I have no coding skills so I can't fix it.
Here is the code that returns an error:
<?php

try {
    $videoId = getLiveVideoID('CHANNEL_ID');

    // Output the Chat URL
    echo "The Chat URL is https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=".$videoId;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Echo the generated error
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}

// The method which finds the video ID
function getLiveVideoID($channelId)
{
    $videoId = null;

    // Fetch the livestream page
    if($data = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel='.$channelId))
    {
        // Find the video ID in there
        if(preg_match('/\'VIDEO_ID\': \"(.*?)\"/', $data, $matches))
            $videoId = $matches[1];
        else
            throw new Exception('Couldn\'t find video ID');
    }
    else
        throw new Exception('Couldn\'t fetch data');

    return $videoId;
}

Can someone help me fix this code so it works? Thanks

There are changes in YouTube's HTML structure due to that your code will not work. The following code will help you to correctly fetch the live stream's VIDEOID and construct the live chat URL.
<?php

function getLiveVideoID($channelId)
{
    $videoId = null;
    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=' . $channelId;
    
    // Use file_get_contents to fetch the HTML content of the page
    $data = file_get_contents($url);

    if ($data !== false) {
        // Use a regular expression to extract the VIDEOID
        if (preg_match('/"videoId":"(.*?)"/', $data, $matches)) {
            $videoId = $matches[1];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Couldn\'t find video ID');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Couldn\'t fetch data');
    }

    return $videoId;
}

try {
    $channelId = 'CHANNEL_ID'; // Replace this with your channel ID
    $videoId = getLiveVideoID($channelId);

    // Output the Chat URL
    echo "The Chat URL is https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=" . $videoId . "&embed_domain=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Echo the generated error
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>


Make sure your server configuration allows file_get_contents to fetch URLs. If not, you might need to use cURL for fetching the content.
Also, If you need real-time updates and the ability to handle changes on YouTube’s end, you should consider using the YouTube Data API. It provides a more robust and reliable way to interact with YouTube content programmatically.

Thanks Eshban for help! To anyone reading this later - this code works however the regex fro the code posted above still doesn't work. I found the proper regex as it is tricky. This is the proper regex to include in the code Eshban posted: {"videoId\":\"(.*?)\"}
